# ImportError or ModuleNotFound error when launching a program using crontab

Tags: python

I am new to coding and Python and have read a lot of similar questions about absolute/relative imports of modules but I cannot understand why my cronjob isn't working.

When I run from the terminal: `python3 example.py` the program runs without issue.

However when I schedule a cronjob to run "example.py", the program fails to run due to an ImportError. The first time it failed was due to a ModuleNotFound error, so I reinstalled the module in question (pyautogui) which seemed to solve that error.

I have tried using `from . import pyautogui, os, time, smtplib, traceback` instead of just `import xyz` but that brings up "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package".

Can anyone help explain in simple terms what's going on here? Or point me in the direction of reading I can do to understand how terminal/cronjob is attempting to execute my program?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help explain in simple terms what's going on here? Or point me in the direction of reading I can do to understand how terminal/cronjob is attempting to execute my program?

Okay. Crontab programs are run under a different environment than the one in the terminal.

The surest way to check this is to run this bash script from crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
set > /tmp/set.txt
```

It will dump the whole environment (probably you only need `$PATH` though) to "/tmp/set.txt".

Run the same script from terminal, saving to a different file. If you compare the two, you'll notice differences, for example again in the `PATH`.

And, you've guessed it, `python` uses `PATH` to find its various bits and pieces (and for that matter, *which* python is run if several are present *also* depends on PATH).

In the crontab file, you should notice, near the top, an assignment to both the `SHELL` variable and the `PATH` variable. Those are the values used by all following commands.

You should probably be able to set the PATH value to the same value you get from terminal, but keep in mind that you might disrupt the operation of any other script in the same crontab (that is why you should rather make use of `/etc/cron.d` files).

Comment: Much appreciate your help. As you said, the PATH was different in the two bash files that I created.  

I have opened the crontab file in TextEdit and it only has one line of text (the time and pathname of program to run). Can I add a PATH variable to the top of this file in Plain Text? I don't understand how to use /etc/cron.d files but will investigate.